# Category name on product url still working after "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" set to no

Tags: magento2, product, category, url, url-rewrite

"Use Categories Path for Product URLs" set to no on admin panel

But everytime I create a new product, it creates rewrite also for `category/product` url

So both of them work: `example.com/category/product` and `example.com/product`

But I don't want Magento to create automatically the category inside the product url automatically, does anyone know how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

After that, you must reindex and refresh the cache.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: it's not working, in the category page the product link has no category name, but it still creates the rewrite url for both link (with and without category name) when I create a new product.